A completeness approach to Maltzev conditions
In universal algebra, there's a classic theorem which says that for any variety of algebras $\mathcal{V}$ the following are equivalent:

Every homomorphic relation $S\subseteq X\times Y$ where $X,Y\in \mathcal{V}$, is difunctional

There exists a ternary term $p$ such that $p(x,x,y)= y$ and $p(y,x,x) = y$ for all $x,y$


Where a difunctional relation $R$ is one which satisfies the following implication:
$$xRu \land yRu\land yRv \implies xRv $$
The proof proceeds as follows:
Let $x,y\in X$ be some elements of an algebra in $\mathcal{V}$. Consider the sub-algebra (homomorphic relation) on $X\times X$, $$S=\langle (x,x), (y,x), (y,y)\rangle$$
Since this is a sub-algebra generated by three elements, we can write it as
$$S=\{p((x,x),(y,x),(y,y))| p\mbox{ is a ternary term}\}$$
And by difunctionality the element $(x,y)\in S$ hence there is a ternary term $p$ such that
$$p((x,x),(y,x),(y,y)) = (x,y)$$
applying it componentwise we see
$$p(x,y,y)= x \land p(x,x,y)= y$$
So it seems like $p$ is the ternary term we're looking for, however $p$ can potentially depend on our choice of $x,y$, so we can't quite conclude what we want. The standard way to proceed from here is to consider some appropriate free algebra, find a similar term $p$ which works for two generators there, and show that in fact this $p$ works universally. This was not my first instinct, instead I want to try to use the completeness theorem of first order logic, but I am struggling with the formulation, and so my question is really a question about whether my vague idea can be turned into a rigorous proof, or if it is simply flawed:
My Idea: The statement "For any $x,y$ there exists a ternary term $p$ such that $p(x,x,y)= y$ and $p(x,y,y)= x$" is true for every algebra in a variety where homomorphic relations are difunctional.Although the Theory of varieties is a first order one, this statement does not belong to the typical theory, since we are quantifying over terms. However, it seems like terms, which can be formally thought of as elements of the term algebra, are not out of reach of an appropriate first order theory. Perhaps we can extend the language and theory so that the above statement is in fact first order. Our meta-leval proof in the first part of this question shows that this statement is in fact true, and so by the completeness theorem for first order logic, we should be able to deduce it, and yet the theory of our variety consists only of universally quantified equations, and it seems like any existential proof for a term would necessarily involve explicitly constructing such a term, so if we fix $x,y$, carry out the deduction, then the $p_{x,y}$ we obtain should work for any other pair of elements.
I am not claiming this proof is rigorous, it is simply an idea, I am asking whether this can be made rigorous, and whether this is a technique that is already used in universal algebra.

I believe the same result, stated in category-theoretic language, is described here. The proof does indeed use the free algebra on three generators.

What is a homomorphic relation?

@AlexKruckman apologies, I see this term is not as commonly used as I believed. It is simply a sub-algebra of a product of two algebras. (So that congruences are precisely homomorphic equivalence relations)

I see, thanks. The compactness theorem can easily get us a finite list of terms $p_1,\dots,p_n$ such that for any $x$ and $y$ in any algebra in $\mathcal{V}$, there is some $i$ such that $p_i(x,x,y)=y$ and $p_i(y,x,x)=y$. But I don't see how to get a single term.
